# Faster reload of components in Angular

Tags: angular, routes, refresh

I have created two Angular components: one for creating a new post and one for displaying all posts. After I press the button for creating a post I am being redirected to my PostList component, where all my posts are displayed. I used `window.location.href`, so that the PostList page can reload automatically, so that the new post appears without the need of manually refreshing. The problem is it's very slow, and it actually requires two refreshes, one when creating the post and one when refreshing the posts list. Is there a faster way to navigate to the post list and display the new post without manually refreshing the page? If I'm using `router.navigateByUrl('/posts')` I must manually refresh the page so that the new post appears, which is not desired.

```
export class PostCreateComponent implements OnInit {

  model: any = {};
  @Output() newContent = new EventEmitter();
   
  publishNewPost() {
    this.postService.createPost(this.model).subscribe(newPost => {
      this.model = newPost;
       this.newContent.emit(model);
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/posts');      
    });
}
}
```

```
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {

  posts: Post[];
  pagination: Pagination;
  postParams: PostParams = new PostParams();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadPosts();
  }

  loadPosts() {
    this.postService.getPosts(this.postParams).subscribe(posts=> {
      this.posts = posts.result;
      this.pagination = posts.pagination;
     });
  }

 addNewContent(content: Post) { this.posts.push(content) }

}
```

For creating posts:

```
<form #postForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="createPost(this.model)" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

PostList:

```
<div  class=" container mt-3" >
         <span *ngFor="let post of posts">
             <app-post-card (newContent)="addNewContent($event)" 
                [post]="post" class="item" ></app-post-card>
         </span>
</div>
```

PostService:

```
getPosts(postParams: PostParams) {
    var response = this.postCache.get(Object.values(postParams).join('-'));

    if (response) {
      return of(response);
    }

    let params = this.getPaginationHeaders(postParams.pageNumber, postParams.pageSize);

    params = params.append('orderBy', postParams.orderBy);

    return this.getPaginatedResult<Post[]>(this.baseUrl + 'posts', params)
    .pipe(map(response => {
        this.postCache.set(Object.values(postParams).join('-'), response);

        return response;
    }));

  }
createPost(model: any) {
     return this.http.post<Post>(this.baseUrl + 'posts/create', model);
}
```

Comment: you can use @Output and just push your post into your array of posts in parent component on creating one, second option is to have rxjs Subject, subscribing to it in parent component, when there is change, you just call this.posts.push(change) and in your child component on submiting your post you do this.subject.next(post)

Comment: I have tried using @Output, but it's probably not ok, cause it doesn't work. I have updated my answer.

Comment: `<app-post-card (newContent)="addNewContent($event)...>` and in your ts file `addNewContent(content) { this.posts.push(content) }`, you dont need to do anything with your `loadPosts()` function

Comment: Ok so i have added the addNewContent(content) to my code in the question, but it still doesn't work. Is the code from publishNewPost() ok? Or have I missed something else?

Comment: it looks ok, does your backend returns inserted post ? try `console.log(newPost)` in your `publishNewPost()` to see if your published post is returned from backend ... if its not, then you have to delete `this.model = newPost`

Comment: The post is returned. I meant that I still have to manually refresh the post list page so that the new post appears.

Comment: I think the problem is that it's actually not child-parent communication, since the PostCreateComponent is not a child of PostListComponent. Can  I use something like ngOnChanges in my PostListComponent?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PostService which can be used for communicating between the two components.
In that service, create a posts list variable for various posts and a behaviorSubject (rxjs) which will always emit the posts list whenever it is updated.

Create a public method to append the new posts in the post.
Create a public method which will return behaviorSubject as observable.

PostService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class PostsService {
    private postsList: string[] = [];

    private $posts: BehaviorSubject<string[]> = new BehaviorSubject<string[]>(this.postsList);

    constructor() { }

    public getPostsObservable(): Observable<string[]> {
        return this.$posts.asObservable();
    }

    public addPost(post: string): void {
        this.postsList.push(post);
        this.$posts.next(this.postsList);
    }

}
```

Then in the AddPost Component, subscribe to the above service and use its addpost method.

AddPost Component:

```
export class AddPost {

    constructor(private postsService: PostsService) {}

    public addNewPost(post) {
        this.postsService.addPost(post);
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <input type="text" (change)="addNewPost($event.target.value)">
</div>
```

ShowPost Component:

```
export class ShowPost implements OnInit {

    public postsList: string[] = [];
    
    constructor(private postsService: PostsService) {}
    
    ngOnInit() {
        this.postsService.getPostsObservable().subscribe(postsList => {
            this.postsList = postsList;
        });
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div *ngFor="let post of postsList">
         {{post}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I already had a postservice, I've updated my code in the question.

Comment: The service which you mentioned in the question is for getting the post from the backend. If you will check my answer, this is a separate injectable service, which is used for communicating between the two sibling components.